modifying OpenAPI schema names with Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.OpenApi
How can I influence the generated names for OpenAPI schemas when using the NuGet package Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.OpenApi 1.5.1?
I'm creating an Azure Function using c# and .NET 8. I've set the OpenApi__Version to v3 in the local.settings.json.
Assume I have the following class for request bodies:
public class DummyRequestModel
{
    /* ... */
}

This will generate the schema name dummyRequestModel in the Swagger document. However I'd like the generated schema name to be notSoDummyRequestModel. How can I achieve this?

This customize-generated-model-names-swagger-ui might be helpful.
